# Convert VB to C# 'GetCustomAttribute'

Tags: c#, vb.net

i would like to translate this function in C#;

```
Private Shared Sub GetTypes(ByVal AssemblyName As String)
        Dim ass As Assembly = Assembly.Load(AssemblyName)
        For Each value As Type In ass.GetTypes()
            Dim methods() As MethodInfo = value.GetMethods()
            Dim InstanceType As MessageHandler
            For Each method As MethodInfo In methods
                [color=#40BF00]InstanceType = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(method, GetType(MessageHandler), False)[/color]
                If InstanceType Is Nothing Then
                    Continue For
                End If
                Dim pack As DofusNetworkMessage = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(InstanceType.MessageType), DofusNetworkMessage)
                Dim instance As InstanceInfo = New InstanceInfo(pack.ProtocolID, InstanceType.MessageType, method)
                Func.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, InstanceInfo)(pack.ProtocolID, instance))
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

I obtained this

```
private static void InitializeFrames()
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("SmartBot.Engine");
        foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            MessageHandler InstanceType = null;

            foreach (MethodInfo Method in type.GetMethods())
            {
                [color=#FF0000]InstanceType = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Method, typeof(MessageHandler), false);[/color]
                if (InstanceType == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                NetworkMessage pack = (NetworkMessage)Activator.CreateInstance(InstanceType.MessageType);
                InstanceInfo instance = new InstanceInfo(pack.ProtocolId, InstanceType.MessageType, Method);
                Handles.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, InstanceInfo>(pack.ProtocolId, instance));
            }

        }
    }
```

I have a problem with this line:

```
InstanceType = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Method, typeof(MessageHandler), false);
```

I get this error;
Impossible to convert implicitly the type ' System. Attribute ' in ' SmartBot. Engine. Frame. MessageHandler '. An explicit conversion exists (is a cast missing?)

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to cast to `MessageHandler`:

```
InstanceType = (MessageHandler)System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Method, typeof(MessageHandler), false);
```

The clue is in this part of the error message: *An explicit conversion exists (**is a cast missing?**)*

Answer (score 0):

The exception message is telling you that you cannot implicitly convert an `Attribute` to a `MessageHandler`. The [System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130865%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function returns an `Attribute` -- you need to explicitly cast to `MessageHandler`:

```
InstanceType = (MessageHandler)System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Method, typeof(MessageHandler), false);
```